# Extract IP or URL without square brackets, regex only

Tags: regex

Please help with regex for the following task:
I have IP and URL in the following form - **192.168.1[.]1**, **site[.]com**.

Is it possible to extract objects without square brackets using ***only*** regex? The result should be like this - **192.168.1.1**, **site.com**.

Here's what I got using the [IP example](https://regex101.com/r/FpYQZS/1).
"Non-capturing group" does not help when I put the whole expression in parentheses.

Comment: Non-capturing groups do not work the way you expect, because the texts they match are always consumed (=added to the overal, whole match). You can't match discontinuous string portions into a single group within one match operation.

Answer (score 0):

The regex to replace the brackets with an empty string should be

```
\[|\]
```

You can test it out here:
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4P055A/1)

Answer (score 0):

What language do you use? Here is the JavaScript code, which you can easily map to another language:

```js
const input = '192.168.1[.]1, site[.]com'
let output = input.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '');
console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.1, site.com
```

Explanation:

- `[\[\]]` - character class containing `[` and `]`
- `g` flag to repeat globally, e.g. find chars in character class
- replace: empty string, e.g. delete what is in the character class